# Workaround for DML Operation after HTTP Response

Tags: salesforce, apex

I need to make a http request and on a successful response, create and insert a record. Here's a snippet of the code

```
public static Collaboration__c createGroupCollaboration(Sub_Folder__C folder, String groupId, string role, String ProfId){
    Box__c box = Box__c.getInstance();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://test.api');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+box.BoxAccess_Token__c);
    req.setBody('{"item": { "id": "'+folder.CF_box_folder_id__c+'", "type": "folder"}, "accessible_by": { "id": "'+groupId+'", "type": "group" }, "role": "'+role+'"}');
    HTTPResponse res = new Http().send(req);
    if(res.getStatuscode() >= 200 && res.getStatusCode() <= 299){
        Collaborationwrapper cw = new Collaborationwrapper();
        cw = (Collaborationwrapper)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),Collaborationwrapper.class);
        Collaboration__c resCollab = new Collaboration__c(BoxCollaboration_Id__c = cw.Id,Role__c= cw.role,BoxFolder_Id__c= folder.CF_box_folder_id__c,Sub_folder__c= folder.id,BoxGroup_Id__c=groupId,SFUser_Email__c = 'group@test.com',SFProfile_Id__c = ProfId);
        return resCollab;
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This class returns a collaboration that will be inserted. When I comment the insert, everything works. When I enable the insert, however, I get the following error: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out.

I need to insert these records ONLY when the operation is successful.

I need to do this for delete too, but I assume the same method will apply to both operations.

I know you're not supposed to do DML after a callout... but how else would I create the record on a successful response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have it other way around. You can have callout first, then DML.

You do something in SF = you start a transaction. It has to commit (succeed) or rollback. If you do DML - you get a lock in the database. Maybe on single record, maybe on whole table. And then you want to make a callout? You'd hold the database hostage for up to 2 minutes, at mercy of external system. No other DMLs in this table would succeed. So SF blocks it by design.

But it's perfectly OK to make callout first, then DML.

Have you tried running this standalone? For 1 record (file or whatever it is). If you're getting the error you might be calling it in a loop and then 2nd iteration is the one that throws. Have a closer look at the debug log.

Or maybe there really was an insert before this code, for example if you run it off a trigger... In that case you need async apex (`@future`, a `Queueable`, batch job etc)

Comment: That's great food for thought. This class runs off the opportunity trigger... but whenever I comment out the insert in the trigger it runs without errors. There is a loop, though. I'll do some investigating but for now your answer satisfies my question.